# CDKTF not recognizing libraries outside of python standard library

Tags: python, terraform, aws-cdk, pipfile, terraform-cdk

I am unable to run cdktf because cdktf won't work with packages installed from PyPI. I need cdktf to be able to install / access packages installed from PyPI.

```
$ cdktf diff

⠏  Synthesizing
[2022-11-11T14:03:01.343] [ERROR] default - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jcbcodes/workspace/project/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    from utils.foo import bar
  File "/Users/jcbcodes/workspace/project/utils/foo.py", line 5, in <module>
    import boto3
ERROR: cdktf encountered an error while synthesizing

Synth command: pipenv run python main.py
Error:         non-zero exit code 1

Command output on stderr:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/jcbcodes/workspace/project/main.py", line 25, in <module>
        from utils.foo import bar
      File "/Users/jcbcodes/workspace/project/utils/foo.py", line 5, in <module>
        import boto3
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'




⠹  Synthesizing
```

boto3 is installed in my python virtual env. I also added boto3 to the Pipfile. I am unclear how to install packages listed under `[packages]` in the Pipfile.
My Pipfile contains the following

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[requires]
python_version = "3"

[packages]
cdktf = "~=0.13.3"
pytest = "*"
boto3 = "1.26.6"
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have a Pipfile I'd expect your app command in your cdktf.json looks something like this: `pipenv run python main.py`. As you can see python is executed through [Pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/). You can use [`pipenv install`](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/#basic-commands-and-concepts) to install the dependencies and then use it as you normally would in your python program.

Comment: New to Terraform CDK, tried to run [aws-eks](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk/tree/main/examples/python/aws-eks) locally, this comment was very useful to realize how to fix this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cdktf'`, i.e `pipenv install cdktf`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because the CDK uses `pipenv` to manage packages and dependencies. To solve it, run `pipenv install <package>` for whatever package cause you the problem.

In general, `cdktf` can only work with the packages in the `Pipeile` listed like this:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[requires]
python_version = "3"

[packages]
cdktf = "~=0.15.5"
<myPackageName> = "*"
```

You can also extract a `requirements.txt` file and install it using `pipenv` like this: `pipenv install -r path/to/requirements.txt`